# Update Altium designer schematics library and keep values unchanged

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, footprint

Whenever I choose a schematic library like a resistor and use Tools > Update Schematic button, all values of resistors that are set in my schematic document are reset to the library default value e.g. 1k Ohms.

Is there a method to keep the values unchanged upon updating?

Comment: Have you asked Altium?

Answer (score 2):

You mean Tools >> Update From Libraries ...?

In this case choose "Replace selected attributes of symbols on sheets", click on "Advanced" and uncheck the parameters you want to keep (e.g. "Value").